# Limiting Amount of Rows in List View

Tags: vb.net

Simple enough question, how would I be able to limit the amount of rows on a ListView to the amount of items/rows that actually contain information. I know how to count the rows with items by using this code

```
ListView1.Items.Count
```

But how can I limit the amount of rows the listview has to the amount of items?

Comment: Can you limit the number of items your provide to the ListView? Filter out any items in the list that are not null and use that as the list you pass to you ListView?

Comment: @karkum The listview is populated by an SQL Table, so it should only receive however many rows are in the table - which is currently two for testing purposes. But my listview contains many more rows below the two rows that contain information...

Comment: "The listview is populated by an SQL Table, so it should only receive however many rows are in the table" No! you should *not* simply fetch everything from the DB, modify the query so that it returns the data you actually want to show, nothing more. Or at the bare minimum, filter the data afterwards instead of simply displaying the whole result set.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, I'm aware of SQL and creating views to limit the amount of information the users can receive. That's been done. I've realized that the listview creates rows based on the size of the listview, so that should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a version of .Net that includes LINQ (3.5+), you get some really nice features which help a lot. These apply to any `IQueryable` including `IList`..

```
Dim MyList = [Some code to get hundreds of items]

Dim MyShortList = MyList.Take(30)
```

You can also implement paging very easily by using `Skip`...

```
Dim MyShortListPage2 = MyList.Skip(30).Take(30)
```

You should look into using the Entity framework or equivalents which implement `IQueryable`. These reduce memory overhead by using deferred processing aka Lazy Loading.

In short, if I were to do the following using the EF:

```
Dim Users = DBContext.Set(Of Users)
```

`Users` won't actually contain all users in the database, instead it will contain the *query* to get all users. If I did `Users.First`, it would run the query against SQL to get the first user. If instead, I did `Users.Where(function(x) x.Age=30).First` it would only query SQL for the first user whose age is 30.

Thus, IQueryable lets you pare down a dataset quickly using the power of the underlying provider instead of doing it in-memory.

If, instead, I did

```
Dim Users = DBContext.Set(Of Users).ToList()
```

It would retrieve all users from the database into memory. The `ToList()` is what forces this to happen. A `List` has to be stored in local memory, an `IQueryable` does not, it can run the appropriate query at the last possible moment and get as little as possible to satisfy your request.

Whether you want this to happen or not depends on the use case.